# Huawei airtel dongle not showing up

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem, huawei

i have installed ubuntu 12.04 and connected my airtel 3G data card. after blinking there is no response. but i checked using lsusb command. it shows my device.

```
bus 003 device 004: id 12d1:1446 huawei tech corp E1552/E1800(hspa modem)
```

Comment: So post please output of `lsusb` to your question.

Comment: bus 003 device 004: id 12d1:1446 huawei tech corp E1552/E1800(hspa modem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `sudo -H gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/50-huawei-e1552.rules`

And paste to the editor these lines

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1",
ATTR{idProduct}=="1446",
RUN+="/lib/udev/modem-modeswitch -v 0x%s{idVendor} -p 0x%s{idProduct} -t option-zerocd"
```

Save the file.

Then run in terminal

```
sudo service udev restart
```

After that you will be able to crate a new connection in Network Manager.

Comment: thanks very very much. it really worked. at the same time can you please tell how to check 3G balance now

Comment: @Ekaveera If it worked, then you can accept the answer by clicking "bird" at the left. How to check balance you should ask your provider. But to send/receive SMS and USSD you can install `modem-manager-gui`.

Comment: but after some time, i am unable to view my  mobile broadband icon in network manager. when i restart the pc then only it is appearing. what might be the issue?

Comment: @Ekaveera And how and when does it disappear?

Comment: after A while my usb modem gets automatically disconnected. at that time the icon vanishes.

Comment: reply to my problem

Comment: @Ekaveera This maybe worth asking another question. But I think it is a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the best solution is to use the program that is shipped with the device itself. This is especially true with Huawei dongles.

- Plug your Huawei dongle. It would be mounted as a CD Rom. Open it up
  and and there will be a `tar.gz` file in a directory named `Linux`.
- Copy that tar.gz to your desktop or somewhere.
- Extract it

  ```
  tar -xzvf filename.tar.gz
  ```
- Open a terminal and run the install.sh file

  ```
  ./install.sh
  ```
- Once installed a program will be appear on your Ubuntu dash which you can use to connect to internet as same as you'd do in a Windows machine.