# Airtel data card not detecting on ubunty 16.04 TLS

Tags: networking, 16.04

I tried everything from 2012-2016 old post solution but nothing works. The same airtel Data card is working fine in Windows but not in latest Ubuntu. I have updated Ubuntu to the latest one with all patched and software upgrade. Anyone else is also having same problem? or I am the only one lucky.

Can somebody help?

Syslog activity:

```
Machiname kernel: [13555.873179] usb-storage 3-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jul  1 19:54:54 Machiname kernel: [13555.873313] scsi host21: usb-storage 3-7:1.0
Jul  1 19:54:54 Machiname kernel: [13555.873411] usb-storage 3-7:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jul  1 19:54:54 Machiname kernel: [13555.873486] scsi host22: usb-storage 3-7:1.1
Jul  1 19:54:54 Machiname mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7"
Jul  1 19:54:54 Machiname mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 14 was not an MTP device
Jul  1 19:54:54 Machiname systemd[1]: Starting USB_ModeSwitch_3-7:1.0...
Jul  1 19:54:54 Machiname usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[11570]: Could not read attribute: No such file or directory
Jul  1 19:54:55 Machiname kernel: [13556.874490] scsi 22:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   SD Storage       2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Jul  1 19:54:55 Machiname kernel: [13556.874830] sd 22:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Jul  1 19:54:55 Machiname kernel: [13556.874925] scsi 21:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Jul  1 19:54:55 Machiname kernel: [13556.877964] sd 22:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Jul  1 19:54:55 Machiname kernel: [13556.878808] sr 21:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
Jul  1 19:54:55 Machiname kernel: [13556.878896] sr 21:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
Jul  1 19:54:55 Machiname kernel: [13556.878945] sr 21:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
Jul  1 19:54:54 Machiname usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[11570]: message repeated 3 times: [ Could not read attribute: No such file or directory]
Jul  1 19:54:55 Machiname usb_modeswitch: switch device 12d1:1446 on 003/014
Jul  1 19:54:56 Machiname usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[11570]: Could not read attribute: No such file or directory
Jul  1 19:54:56 Machiname usb_modeswitch[11570]: usb_modeswitch: switched to 12d1:1446 on 3/14
Jul  1 19:54:57 Machiname usb_modeswitch_dispatcher[11570]: Unable to open bind list file: No such file or directory
Jul  1 19:54:57 Machiname usb_modeswitch[11570]: usb_modeswitch: add device ID 12d1:1446 to driver option
Jul  1 19:54:57 Machiname usb_modeswitch[11570]: usb_modeswitch: please report the device ID to the Linux USB developers!
Jul  1 19:55:04 Machiname systemd[1]: Started USB_ModeSwitch_3-7:1.0.d
```

Comment: Can you share few links you already tried so that answers are not repeated?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/638520/huawei-airtel-dongle-not-showing-up
  This thread was useful only for one time, it got connected then when I restarted PC then its not working. 


http://askubuntu.com/questions/353478/how-to-use-airtel-4g-lte-dongle-with-ubuntu
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2007622

Just for update when I insert the data card it does not show airtel dialer or detect any usb type thing in the system.

But lsusb is showing the modem with stick